# Unable to receive Push messages but able to connect with the Apple Gateway

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have created the IPA file which is able to receive the push messages. On the other hand I created a PHP module to send the push messages to the Apple Gateway. The PHP part seems to be working fine because there aren't any errors but I' am not able to receive the push messages in iPhone app. To check whether the iPhone is able to receive the push messages or not, I used a "Pusher" app to send the messages and found that it's working fine. Please someone can suggest what could be the reason that I' am not able to receive the messages sent from the PHP module?

Comment: Whenever I faced problems with APNS, I fired a test Notification from the server using my device's deviceToken. If server end works well, then I start checking in the project itself, like whether the permission has been given and whatnot

Comment: Have you done the code on your xcode part to receive the push notification from remote server? You need to add it in app delegate and also you need to insert delegate methods like 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' and 'didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError' and 'didReceiveRemoteNotification'.

Comment: Finally got the solution. We have kept the environment mode as "Sandbox" instead of "Production" After changing the environment things started working.